Why this minus sign before the dot product for a negative pair in the negative sampling loss function?
$$
\mathcal{L} = - \log \sigma \left( v^T_{w_0} v_{w_i} \right)
- \sum_{j = 1}^k \log \sigma \underbrace{\left(- v^T_{w_j} v_{w_i} \right)}_{\text{the part in question}}
$$
The loss of negative sampling consists of two parts.
The first part concerns the observed pair.
The second part concerns the unobserved pairs.
I understand that the dot product of the two words is mapped to the interval 0..1 and represents the probability of observing the two words together. Therefore, I understand that we want -log of this probability to be minimized for the observed pairs.
However, why on earth do we put a minus sign in front of the dot product for an unobserved pair? I've read here and there that it’s because we want a negative value. But nothing guarantees that this quantity will be negative. I mean, if the dot product is negative, adding a minus sign in front will make the result positive!!!
So, I don't understand why the second part of the loss isn't simply: + Sum of probabilities of the k unobserved pairs. A term that we would try to minimize, which would be consistent since these are unobserved pairs.
Something is escaping me and I can’t see what.

Although I don't see enough context to know for sure what all your symbols mean, as an (educated) guess I would like to point out that under a standard interpretation (where $\sigma$ has a certain symmetry property) you can rewrite $\log\sigma(-x)=\log(1-\sigma(x)).$

@whuber At first I did not understand what you tried to say but it's starting to light my brain eventually. Thanks a lot!! I think I got it!!
